# How to use Powershell arguments as regex to rename files?

Tags: regex, powershell, cmd, file-rename

I want to write a simple Powershell script that takes 2 regular expressions as arguments, and renames files in a folder. Here is myscript.ps1 :

```
echo $args[0]
echo $args[1]
Get-ChildItem
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $args[0], $args[1]}
"foo" -replace $args[0], $args[1]
```

I am calling this script from myscript.cmd

```
@echo off
powershell -Command %~dpn0.ps1 %1 %2
```

When i execute `myscript foo bar` from cmd, i get the output

```
foo
bar
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        26.11.2016     15:24         16 foo
bar
```

But my test file `foo`, that i created, is not renamed.

My questions:

- Do i call the Powershell script correctly and pass the arguments in the right way? I think i'll need some kind of quotes around the %1, %2 arguments.
- Why doesnt the file get renamed, altough the `-replace` seems to work?

Comment: Troubleshooting advice: `echo $PWD`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a problem with your idea, you don't filter the files and RegEx doesn't fit in with wildcards, so to get a file named foo your RegEx should look like `^foo$` and if you want to match a file name with an extension it's `^foo\.txt$`

```
$From = [RegEx]($Args[0])
$To =  [RegEx]($Args[1])
Get-ChildItem -file|
  %{if ($_.Name -match $From) {
    Rename-Item $_.Fullname -NewName $To
  } 
}
```

This script does the rename by casting $Args[0] to a RegEx when invoked this way:

```
 .\Rename-RegEx.ps1 "^foo$" bar
```

Answer (score -1):

i dont know why, but you can do it

```
$arg0=$args[0]
$arg1=$args[1]

Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $arg0, $arg1}
```

Comment: But this would also rename foobar.